# Proof of Cauchy shwarz inequality with multiple parts

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

> The aim of this question is to prove the cauchy schwarz inequality.
> Use the fact that $\|\mathbf{x}\|^2 = \mathbf{x} \cdot\mathbf{x} \geq 0$ to show the following:

> a) $\|\|\mathbf{v}\|^2 \mathbf{u} - (\mathbf{u} \cdot \mathbf{v})\mathbf{v}\|^2 = \|\mathbf{v}\|^4 \|\mathbf{u}\|^2 - \|\mathbf{v}\|^2(\mathbf{u}\cdot\mathbf{v})^2$

I got this part. It was fairly straightforward.

> b) Use part a) and the fact that $\|\mathbf{x}\|^2 = \mathbf{x} \cdot\mathbf{x} \geq 0$ to show that $|\mathbf{u}\cdot\mathbf{v}|\leq\|\mathbf{u}\|\|\mathbf{v}\|$

I'm stuck here. I know what the cauchy schwarz inequality is and I've seen various proofs of it which I get, but I'm not sure how we use part a) for this proof. Can anyone offer any insight?

Comment: The left side is greater than or equal to $0$. So, the right is. The right being $\geq0$ gives what you want after cancelling $\|v\|^2$. This can be done only if $\|v\|\neq0$, but if it were equal to zero, CS is true too.

Comment: I got it now. I can't believe I didn't notice that!

Answer (score 2):

Here it is a proof I like. Let $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle:V\times V\to\textbf{F}$ be an inner product where $V$ is a vector space. Let $u\in V$. If $u = 0$, then clearly $\langle u,v\rangle = 0 \leq \|u\|\|v\|$ for every $v\in V$. Suppose otherwise that $u\neq 0$. Then define $w\in V$ as follows:
\begin{align*}
w = \frac{\langle u,v\rangle}{\langle u,u\rangle}u
\end{align*}

As it can be seen, $v = w + (v - w)$. Once $w\perp(v - w)$, one concludes that
\begin{align*}
\|v\|^{2} = \langle v,v\rangle = \|w\|^{2} + \|v - w\|^{2} \geq \|w\|^{2} = \frac{|\langle u,v\rangle|^{2}}{\|u\|^{2}} \Rightarrow |\langle u,v\rangle| \leq \|u\|\|v\|
\end{align*}

Hopefully this helps!